# Sql Server Reporting Services – SharePoint feature missing

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I am trying to add Reporting Services – SharePoint feature to my computer sql server installation.

I am currently using Sql Server 2012 Enterprise on a 32 bit computer

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (Intel X86)
    Feb 10 2012 19:13:17
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Unfortunately, in Shared features I don't have the Reporting Services items mentioned in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx

Could it be because I don't have Sharepoint installed on my computer?
Or maybe, because my computer is 32 bit?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: this is sql express edition?

Comment: No.You can read the full version in the post.

Comment: @Gyonder Run the SQL 2012 setup again, choose the option add features to an existing instance. Just have a look at that to check if you are missing any features which needs to be installed.

Comment: @Punter015 it is already all I could install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 64 bit computer [Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210640.aspx#bkmk_reportserverDB) says
computer must meet the following software requirements

```
The add-in is 64-bit only, which is a requirement of SharePoint 2010 
products and technologies.
```

In this article you can check `Report Server Database Requirements`

```
If you want to install Reporting Services and a SharePoint product instance on the same computer, you can run SQL Server Express and another edition of 
SQL Server side-by-side on the same computer or you can use the same instance of the Database Engine for the SharePoint configuration and content databases
if you choose the Advanced installation option when installing a
SharePoint product . If you choose the Basic installation option instead, 
the SharePoint Setup program will install SQL Server Embedded Edition
as an internal component and use that instance to host the SharePoint databases.
```

[reporting servides in sharepoint mode](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=OjHGoNOV9BYC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=Sql%20Server%20Reporting%20Services%20%E2%80%93%20SharePoint%20feature&source=bl&ots=WMlifNFRri&sig=nJKWQYdeKbr08dCyJ8j4CWlh5Bo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OH7zUrbYIOazyAG6u4Fg&ved=0CF4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: As I wrote, my computer is 32 bit. Anyway, I suppose I need 64 bit to install that feature.

Comment: yeah you need 64 bit..@Gyonder if my answer useful mark answer as useful